# AspNet Core Identity, how set options.Cookie.SameSite for .net core 1.1

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, asp.net-core-1.1

I am facing issue with same site cookie policy in chrome, application is built using .NET core 1.1 version, is there any workaround to fix cookies same site issue in .NET core without updating the .NET core version.

````
          app.UseIdentityServer();

          var schemeName = "oidc";
          var dataProtectionProvider = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IDataProtectionProvider>();
          var distributedCache = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IDistributedCache>();

          var dataProtector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector(
              "protector",
              typeof(string).FullName, schemeName,
              "v1");

          var dataFormat = new CachedPropertiesDataFormat(distributedCache, dataProtector);


          app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(new MicrosoftAccountOptions()
          {
              StateDataFormat = dataFormat,
              ClientId = Configuration.GetSection("AuthenticationProviders:Microsoft:ClientID").Value,
              ClientSecret = Configuration.GetSection("AuthenticationProviders:Microsoft:ClientSecret").Value
          });

          app.UseFacebookAuthentication(new FacebookOptions
          {
              ClientId = Configuration.GetSection("AuthenticationProviders:Facebook:ClientID").Value,
              ClientSecret = Configuration.GetSection("AuthenticationProviders:Facebook:ClientSecret").Value
          });

          app.UseTwitterAuthentication(new TwitterOptions
          {
              ConsumerKey = Configuration.GetSection("AuthenticationProviders:Twitter:ConsumerKey").Value,
              ConsumerSecret = Configuration.GetSection("AuthenticationProviders:Twitter:ConsumerSecret").Value,
              RetrieveUserDetails = true
          });

          app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions
          {
              ClientId = Configuration.GetSection("AuthenticationProviders:Google:ClientID").Value,
              ClientSecret = Configuration.GetSection("AuthenticationProviders:Google:ClientSecret").Value
          });

          app.UseMvc();```
````

Comment: Can you provide some code example of how you have configured your application?

Comment: added @CameronTinker